# Need assistance with output of minutes using mod in C?

Tags: c, time, floating-point, codeblocks, modulus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int temperature, time;
    float minutes;

    printf("What is the Fahrenheit temperature?\n");
    scanf("%d",&temperature);

    time = (5 - (temperature - 90) / 5);
    minutes = ((5 % time) * 60);


    if (temperature >= 90)
        printf("It will rain at approximately %d hours and %f minutes after noon.\n", time, minutes);

    else
        printf("It will not rain today.\n");


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

I am using the C programming language. This is homework but its okay to use some bits from the web as long as its not the whole code. Anyways, If the current temperature is 93f  `time = 4.4` so I would like to output:

`It will rain approximately 4 hours and 24 minutes after noon` but the output instead is:

`It will rain at approximately 5 hours and 0.000000 minutes after noon`

EDIT:
I get an error now that states invalid operands to binary % (have int and float) Please be patient with me LOL I am trying to learn.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
    {
    int current_temp;
    float remaining_minutes, time;

    printf("What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?\n");
    scanf("%d",&current_temp);

    time = (5 - (current_temp - 90) / 5);
    ERROR**** remaining_minutes = ((5 % time) * 60);


    if (current_temp >= 90)
        printf("It will rain at approximately %d hours and %f minutes after noon.\n", time);

    else
        printf("It will not rain today.\n");


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your time as a `float` as well. Right now you are dividing integers by integers so you are only getting whole numbers.

Comment: I tried to. I added new edited code but it didn't work. Can you please explain more. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

How about 
    mins = (time % 1) * 60?

Edit: or mins = (time*10 % 10) * 6. On my phone so can't really test.

Comment: it didn't work. I added edited code.

Answer (score 0):

`time` is an `int`.  You can't expect it to hold a floating point number.

Comment: At the top I set it as int, can you tell me more, I am a noob.

Answer (score 0):

time = (5 - (temperature - 90) / 5);

time,5,90 are integers so time =  5 - 0 ...wich is 5

trie to use float time and

```
time = (5.0 - (float)(temperature - 90) / 5);
```